# Safety of unrestricted_access

Tags: ada

I have a complicated situation so I hope I can explain it properly.

I am using unchecked_access in combination with Ada.Finalization.Controlled types to pass references to vectors to an out of scope protected hashed map type on the Initialize procedure and removing references in the protected map on the finalize procedure. This way I thought I could assure that it would be impossible for any tasks to see out of scope references in the map.

However, the way I have the protected map organized snap shots are taken at each instance that is it used (effectively making it a normal hashed_map) which during the course of it being used vector references could go out of scope and the snap shot would still have the reference and attempt to access it.

I could see this creating 2 problems, either I am creating dangling pointers and trying to reference freed memory or my snapshot of the references is keeping the memory alive and I am leaving garbage around. I made a test to see what would happen and it seems the memory is still alive but is this really the case? Are there any other problems with my organization?

```
with Ada.Containers; use Ada.Containers;
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Test is
  package V_Integer is new Ada.Containers.Vectors(Positive, Integer);
  use V_Integer;
  type V_Access is access all Vector;
  Bar : V_Access;
begin
  declare
  Foo : aliased Vector;
  begin
    Bar := Foo'unrestricted_Access;
    Foo.Append(3);
    Foo.Append(5);
    Put_Line("In scope: " & count_type'image(Length(Bar.all)));
  end;
  -- Will this reference always exist? Does it need to be freed?
  Put_Line("Out of scope: " & count_type'image(Length(Bar.all))); 
end Test;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
begin
  declare
  Foo : aliased Vector;
  begin
    Bar := Foo'unrestricted_Access;
    Foo.Append(3);
    Foo.Append(5);
    Put_Line("In scope: " & count_type'image(Length(Bar.all)));
  end;
  -- Will this reference always exist? Does it need to be freed?
  Put_Line("Out of scope: " & count_type'image(Length(Bar.all))); 
end Test;
```

`Foo` will be an object of type `Vector`, and it will probably exist on the stack.  This object is itself a relatively small record, maybe about 6 32-bit words in GNAT (give or take a few, I haven't checked).  It contains an access component that is used to get at all the vector's elements, and it contains some other housekeeping information.  `Bar` will point to that small 6-word record.  Essentially it will contain the address of something on the stack.

Since the small record `Foo` exists on the stack, when it goes out of scope, the stack space could be used for something else.  Whether it will happen in this case, I don't know.  But if you have another `declare...begin...end` block after the one in the example, local variables used by the new block could reuse the same stack space.  Or if a procedure is called, that will put different stuff on the stack.  In either case, the stack space previously used by `Foo` will be overwritten.  And `Bar` will still point to the same address, but the area it points to will have been overrun with other data.  So the result is likely to be wrong and could be a disaster.

I don't know if this is exactly how the implementation will work, but no matter how it's implemented, this code is potentially disastrous.  The main things to keep in mind are: (1) If a variable goes out of scope, the space used for that variable may be reused at will; (2) if you use `'Unchecked_Access` (or `'Unrestricted_Access`) to set up a pointer to that variable, then after the variable goes out of scope, accessing data pointed to by the pointer could get you garbage or very bad behavior; (3) variables, whether aliased or not, are not (usually) dynamically allocated and the program does not need to (and cannot) explicitly free them, even if you've created a reference to them with `'Unchecked_Access`.

Comment: Not just *potentially* disastrous! [ARM A.18.2(84)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html#p84) says that Vectors need finalization; the actual elements *will* be freed when the Vector goes out of scope.

Comment: Yes, but will the vectors themselves? I think ajb had the answer in that they could but are not guaranteed to, correct?

Comment: As `Foo` goes out of scope it is finalized, which (with GNAT) frees all the elements so it is (almost) like an empty vector (there are some other components which aren’t reset). That memory is now a target for re-use by the compiler. If you catch it via `Bar` at a point where it hasn’t been trampled on, it still looks more-or-less empty; if it has been trampled on, who knows what will happen?

Comment: @RogerWilco Whether or not the elements are freed is irrelevant.  Even if they aren't (which theoretically could happen if the last thing in the block is assigning the entire vector to another vector), the *pointer* to those elements is part of a record that will be "freed" (i.e. memory could be reused), and `Bar` points to that record, not to any element, which means you won't be able to use `Bar` to get at the elements.

Comment: @Simon Wright Thank you guys for the detailed answers -- I knew the code I was making was bad but did not have a clear reason. I am currently working on a better solution that is safe.

Comment: @RogerWilco I noticed you changed the title, but I don't think it makes a difference.  `'Unrestricted_Access` (provided by GNAT and some other compilers, but not part of the language) is legal in some cases where `'Unchecked_Access` is illegal (i.e. an error at compile time).  For example, if `V_Access` were `access Vector` instead of `access all Vector`, or `Foo` were not `aliased`.  But I believe that if both are legal, as in your case, they do the same thing, and the issues are exactly the same.